# why does some of the classes in my tailwind css not work?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I just installed tailwindcss and some of the classes dont seem to work:

```
<h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline text-yellow-500">
        Hello world!
      </h1>
```

The output is black text, whereas the undereline and the bold styles are there.

```
<h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline text-red-500">
        Hello world!
      </h1>
```

but this code seems to give the required output of red text.

I tried changing the paths of the input css and watched some videos on youtube but none of them seem to work.
I noticed in some videos that some of them had more than 5000 lines of compiled css codes whereas i only had 500 or so lines.
I think i might have some classes missing.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding (`tailwind build ...`) after you save the file where this `h1` is at?

Comment: Try clearing browser cache or force reload.

Comment: @acdcjunior yes i tried as you told and i noticed a warning in the terminal saying no utilities classes were detected in your source file. Any solution to it? it might solve the problem i am facing

Comment: Show us your `tailwind.config.js` and let us know you file structure (where the HTML file is at, and the css with `@tailwind` directive is at)

Comment: I fixed the config file and updated the paths and everything started working, found what the problem was , thanks for the help.